# Load bulk data in HTML table faster

Tags: asp.net, html

I generate an html table from code behind to display data like a grid (Note: I am not using GridView). I then assign that HTML table to a div. But now when data is large (around 2000 rows), it displays a white page like the application has hung.

How do I resolve this issue? I am thinking of showing only 100 rows at a time while other rows are generated in background but I don’t have any idea of how to implement it.
Can anyone help me? You see the type of functionality that I require in Facebook when you scroll down. Please let me know your ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: With javascript or jquery you can achieve that im sure that you can find information about it on google or here there are allot of people that tried/did this before you

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "infinite scrolling." Here's the links to a jQuery plugin that should help you get it going:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Like a lot of other solutions, the specific code will vary depending on your containing HTML and your data source. Post back here if/when you have any specific problems you need a hand with.